# How to use a timer inside a MATLAB function block in Simulink

Tags: matlab

I am working on a model of an electrical distribution network in Simulink, and I want to determine some data after a fault occurs at a certain time. But the problem is that I need to delay the MATLAB function that calculates the data for 0.5 seconds after the fault time. How can I create a timer inside a MATLAB function block to perform this task?

I have tried using the timer function in MATLAB, but it does not work inside a MATLAB function block. I get an error message saying: "Undefined function or variable 'timer'." Is there another way to use a timer in Simulink?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Don't confuse simulator time with computer time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [transport delay](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transportdelay.html) with 0.5 sec then check your error based on the delayed signal if true then take the data point you want.